# Present "view" in a VC that is embedded in a NavController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So basically I am using BLTNboard (a pod) to display Settings for different posts (a TableView). This all works fine, but when I click on a post and go to its comments (picture below), my method doesn't work anymore.

So the main problem: I want to present a "view" when clicking a button, but Xcode doesnt let me present it onto the VC that is embedded in a NavController.

**Code:**

```
boardManager.backgroundViewStyle = .blurredDark
            boardManager.showBulletin(above: self)
```

^ I want to present it on `self`, but that doesnt work and just nothing happens. (on the main VC it works that way)

How the embedded VC looks:

[image]

And how I got from the main VC to that VC:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "commentsVC") as? CommentsViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**My main issue:** The BLTNboard does not show up.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your issue correctly. `boardManager.showBulletin(above: self)` In this place, instead of `self` have you tried `boardManager.showBulletin(above: self. navigationController)` instead. I'm assuming showBulletin is code to present a VC. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: please show your present code

Comment: @RishabhRaghunath tried ```self.navigationController```, but that did now work. And yes, you understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `showBulletin` method would be able to present it's Bulletin VC from your view controller's navigationController.

```swift
if let mainNav = self.navigationController{
   boardManager.showBulletin(above: mainNav)
}
```